# Android Studio First Time Running Error

Tags: android-studio, emulation, haxm

I started following Bucky's tutorials on android development. I installed the jdk, make a JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to the jdk. I installed android studio, as well as the required packages and this is what's coming up:

```
"C:\Users\Vince\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -setspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86
emulator: device fd:732
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
creating window 43 59 329 583
```

I open my sdk manager and I have the following packages installed:

```
-Tools
  + Android SDK Tools
  + Android SDK Platform Tools
  + Android SDK Build Tools

-Android 5.0.1 (API 21)
  + Documentation for Android SDK
  + SDK Platform
  + Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image
  + Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image
  + Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image
  + Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image
  + ARM EABI v7a System Image
  + Intel x86 Atom _64 System Image
  + Intel x86 Atom System Image
  + Google APIs
  + Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
  + Sources for Android SDK

-Extras
  + Android Support Repository
  + Android Support Library
  + Google Repository
  + Google USB Driver
  + Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)
```

I am running a 64 bit windows 8 operating system. If anymore information is required from me, please comment as I have no clue how to solve this. I thought it may be space on my hard drive, but I have almost 361 gigabytes left.

The emulator does run but it stays at saying android. I left it running all night just in case it took a while but when I woke up, it was the same screen.[image: This is the screen it gets stuck at]

Comment: You can check out the answer in this post.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269121/android-studio-emulator-memory-limit

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have downloaded HAXM using AVD Manager or manually from any website.

While installing intelhaxm_android.exe(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
put the RAM space allocation to default which may be 2GB.

I was facing the same problem but it worked after re-installing with 2GB RAM space instead of 1GB which I initially selected.
For complete guidance you can refer to:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 0):

HAXM is not installed yet - follow this tutorial [Haxm Installation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)