# haxm is FINE, but still cannot launch AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I got this annoying issue. Every other posts are discussing haxm, but in my case, it works fine. I also tried to reduce *RAM* of *AVD(1024M, 512M, 256M)*. Just cannot got *AVDs* work.

I got these messages when I attempt to launch an *AVD*.

```
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: device fd:604
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269121/android-studio-emulator-memory-limit yet?

Comment: yes, but I think his problem is haxm, the error message says "HAXM is not working". Mine is different, it seems the problem is not about haxm.

Answer (score 0):

It seams if I chose higher API version (like 21+), RAM assigned to AVD will automatically increased to 1GB, then comes "Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument".

My solution is to choose lower version system images and set AVD RAM as 512 MB.