# Android Emulator Crash in Mac Os

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing new issue after updating the Android SDK.

I am clicking on the Run in the Android Studio.
     1) It opens emulator but during loading the emulator is getting crashing..

Crash Log along with image is attaching here..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to address the warning message? I suppose you don't have enough RAM left after allocating ~3GB to the virtual device . Especially if you are using a Mac with less than 8GB RAM that's an overkill (I haven't tried if it's at all possible to allocate more than 2GB even if you had enough RAM). Try to reduce the emulator RAM to 2GB and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Anyways i find the solution... Solution was after upgrading to 3.3 this issue got resolved...

Answer (score 1):

[This existing stackoverflow question link should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269121/android-studio-emulator-fails-to-start-with-memory-limit-related-error-message)

[avd device setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnjCN.png) choose emulator device with least resolution, it uses less space on disk

[Tip: How to make Android Emulators fast?](https://publishingfirstandroidapp.blogspot.com/2017/10/tip-how-to-make-android-emulators-fast.html)

I would suggest having an alternative emulator always..
you can't depend on one, get Genymotion emulator

---

*install genymotion plugin* for Andriod Studio/eclipse from [plugins](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/)

You also *need genymotion installed* on your system, [download genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)

Comment: I love you answer but the issue was happening in Android Emulator... 

   Anyways i find the solution.  After upgrading the Gradle version to 3.3 in my latest android studio it worked...